# Use a string as a vb function

Tags: vb.net

I have into a string a replace, but I want to use it as a real vb.net function, There are a possibility to do this? For example:

```
dim str as string = "my task"
dim func as string = "Replace(str, " ", "-")"
dim result as string = 'here I must to use func string to have into result "my-task"
```

help me please

Comment: why you need `dim func as string = "Replace(str, " ", "-")"` ?? `Dim result As String = str.Replace(" ", "-")` will gives you the result

Comment: just see this  - http://hastebin.com/alubuxenak.vbs

Comment: I need to use not only this function but more another function, left(), replace(), mid() but this all I have into a string

Comment: replace can be next time so: replace(str, ".",","), I can do this using select case and trying to do for each needed function calculation, but I try to found if there are this possibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
Dim inputString As String = "my task"
Dim methodName As String = "Replace"
Dim arguments = New String() {" ", "-"}

Dim result = CallByName(inputString, methodName, CallType.Method, arguments)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Dim inputString As String = "my task"
Dim result = inputString.Replace(" ", "-")
```

Although it is worth noting:  it is very likely that there are better ways to organize your code. Executing functions from a string have multiple downsides that you might want to avoid.